# when using threading on a function ram accumulates

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using this piece of code to perform  some threading

```
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
        result = pool.apply_async(self.my_love, (request.image_url,))            
        _id = result.get()
        pool.close() 
        pool.join()
```

the problem is as i run this in a loop for multiple urls my ram keeps increasing till it crashes.

Any ideas on how i could fix this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `pool.join()` before close?

Comment: nope let me try

Comment: or after closing the  pool this will help I guess.

Comment: nope this does not help

Comment: Can you give me a scenario what you are trying to achieve? are you scraping data or something else?

Comment: Can you try it without multithreading, to see whether that's the problem or the memory leak also happens with a single thread?